# Matplotlib and SGD

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot this surface. It turns out it was plotted in Matlab. I don’t have access to Matlab so I did the whole thing in python and got the x, y and z for the surface.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Is there any chance that this could be made with matplotlib?

These are the coordinates:

```
learning rate: 
[0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.005,
 0.005,
 0.005,
 0.005,
 0.01,
 0.01,
 0.01,
 0.01,
 0.015,
 0.015,
 0.015,
 0.015]

rmse:

[2.7689,
 2.7687,
 2.7688,
 2.7688,
 0.9809,
 0.9417,
 0.9268,
 0.9231,
 0.9486,
 0.9243,
 0.9306,
 0.9316,
 0.9406,
 0.934,
 0.9381,
 0.9419]

number of epochs:


[10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Comment: You can certainly do surfaces with matplotlib. Have a look at https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `collaborative-filtering` or `recommender-systems` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `matplotlib`).

Comment: Simply because questions here should be shrinked down to the relevant core, which shows your Problem and - ideally - nothing else. And your issue is about plotting a 3D surface in matplotlib, independent from what the underlying data  is about and wants to tell anybody and.... see also [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Tags have to do only with the *content* of the question, not its context; the fact that you may need help with a sorting algorithm to be subsequently used in a spaceship does not qualify the question as being about `space-engineering`.